# how to copy checked rows to another datawindow?

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow

So I have two datawindows, and in the first DW I have a checkbox per row. Now, I want to copy/send the checked or selected rows to the 2nd DW on a click of a button. Can you please enlighten me on how to do this? TIA. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends upon how you have the datawindows set up.  If they are using the same datawindow OBJECT you can simply use the RowCopy method.

```
dw_1.rowsCopy(<start dw_1 row number>, <end dw_1 row number>, 
              Primary!, dw_2, <dw_2 row number BEFORE which you wish to add
              the rows>, Primary!)
```

where `dw_1` has the rows to copy and `dw_2` is the target.

If the datawindows use different datawindow objects (different number of columns, etc.) you need to loop through the source datawindow rows and do a series of SetItem calls to place the data into the target datawindow.